# Cannot edit GCP load balancer

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcp-load-balancer

I deployed a public application in GKE auto-pilot yesterday. Load balancers were correctly provisionned with an HTTPS certificate. My app is correctly reachable.

Now, I want to change the SSL rules of the load balancer. When I try to save it I get a message telling me that all fields must be correct to continue. I don't have a list of errors or fields in error. The button to access problems is hidden despite the message. If I try to edit and save the load balancer without making any modifications, it fails. I tried to edit another load balancer created for GKE and it fails with the same error. I can edit my load balancer that handles redirection from HTTP to HTTPS though.

I tested several times yesterday and again this morning. Any ideas on what the issue can be?

Comment: Did you have tried with API call? or Gcloud CLI? I'm not a GKE intensive user, but your use case make sense: GKE create and remove the GCP resource for you: the VM, the LoadBalancer, the firewall rules,... You can set that with your YAML and the control plane. If you update these resources manually, you will create a difference between the control plane state and the reality and the control plane will try to make the config compliant again. So, the good way is to use the Kubernetes feature and object definition to update what you want in your load balancer.

Comment: I haven't found any documentation to do it with CLI or API call. Do you have links for that?
I need to change SSL rules and associate an IPv6 address. As far as I know I can only associate one address with annotations and I use that for my IPv4, see [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-gce/issues/87). I cloud try the 2 ingress tricks for that though.

Comment: I did another search and found [this](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/ingress-features#configuring_ingress_features_through_frontendconfig_parameters) which should allow me to solve part of my problem. I'll try to test it soon.

Comment: I managed to configure it with `FrontentConfig` (see link above). Your idea was very good. Thanks @guillaumeblaquiere!

Answer (score 1):

Modify the "Host and Path Rules" so that a blue tick can appear. All three checks are required to perform the update.

However we know that this is an interface managed by GKE and [manual changes](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/ingress#ingress_for_external_and_internal_traffic) should not be made as indicated here. The client changes will be overwritten by the Ingress configuration in the GKE project.

You need to modify the YAML and alter the certificate there. This [link](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/ingress#options_for_providing_ssl_certificates) contains how to manage certificates in Google Cloud.

Depending on the type of certificate you are working with, you can choose options that will give you instructions on how to handle the certificates.

If the issue is still not resolved, can you share a screenshot of the error for further investigation.

Comment: Yes, I rely on `BackenConfig` and `FrontendConfig` (details [here](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/ingress-features#configuring_ingress_features_through_frontendconfig_parameters)) to configure the load balancer without edition. I already mananged my certificated correctly, it was mostly for SSL rules.

Comment: thanks, that was my issue

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how are you trying to update/modify your Load Balancer. [I am guessing your are trying to update this using methods outside of GKE.](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/ingress#ingress_for_external_and_internal_traffic)

**Important:**

***Whenever GKE creates an external HTTP(S) load balancer or internal HTTP(S) load balancer through an Ingress object, you should avoid changing the load balancer's configuration using methods outside of GKE. Your customizations to settings for the load balancer's objects – forwarding rules, target proxies, URL maps, backend services, and health checks – are overwritten when new resources changes are applied, during periodic syncs, or during cluster upgrades. If you need to manage an external HTTP(S) load balancer or internal HTTP(S) load balancer outside of GKE, use container native load balancing for standalone NEGs instead.***

Comment: Add already suggested, yes it's a bad idea. I though there was no alternative, but after searching more (see my comment on my question), it's a bad idea and I can to it in another fashion thanks to `BackendConfig` and `FrontendConfig`.